# How long does variable_set last?

Tags: configuration

Is variable_set just creating a session variable or can I retrieve this variable from a cron job?

I can load the page over and over, but I always get this output.  It seems as though the data is not pulled from the variables table, but set only manually each page load.

```
$default_vals = get_defaults_variable_get();
clean_dump($default_vals);

save_defaults_variable_set();

$default_vals = get_defaults_variable_get();
clean_dump($default_vals);
clean_dump($_GET);


function get_defaults_variable_get(){
    $content[sort_direction] = variable_get('inventory_sort_direction');
    $content[threshold] = variable_get('inventory_threshold');
    $content[hide_zero_inventory] = variable_get('inventory_hide_zero_inventory');
    $content[email] = variable_get('inventory_email');
    return $content;
}


function save_defaults_variable_set(){
    //echo 'save defaults';
    variable_set('inventory_sort_direction', $_GET[sort_direction]);
    variable_set('inventory_threshold', $_GET[threshold]);
    variable_set('inventory_hide_zero_inventory', $_GET[hide_zero_inventory]);
    variable_set('inventory_email', $_GET[email]);

}
```

output

```
array
  'sort_direction' => null
  'threshold' => null
  'hide_zero_inventory' => null
  'email' => null
array
  'sort_direction' => string 'DESC' (length=4)
  'threshold' => string '5' (length=1)
  'hide_zero_inventory' => string 'true' (length=4)
  'email' => string 'e@sltwtr.com,bsaltzman@gmail.com' (length=39)
array
  'threshold' => string '5' (length=1)
  'sort_direction' => string 'DESC' (length=4)
  'hide_zero_inventory' => string 'true' (length=4)
  'email' => string 'e@sltwtr.com,bsaltzman@gmail.com' (length=39)
  'save_to_email' => string 'true' (length=4)
  'q' => string '' (length=0)
```

Comment: Presumably the `$_GET` vars aren't what you expect (you should quote your strings by the way, PHP will assume an undefined constant is a string but you'll only get into trouble doing things that way). Which hook are you running this code in?

Comment: I am running it in a module function.  The get vars are as expected.  I am trying to set them permanently with variable_set.  As you can see, on each new page load the variables from variable_get are null.

Comment: Check your settings.php to make sure there aren't any overrides for your vars on `$conf`, and flush any non-db caches (memcache, redis, etc) to be doubly sure. Other than that, check that other custom or contrib modules aren't causing it by disabling them temporarily. `variable_set` and `variable_get` are fundamental functions to Drupal, if they're not working something is up with your installation. And of course make sure you test the `variable_set` with literal strings to rule problems with `$_GET`

Answer (score 1):

Straight from the [docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/variable_set/7):

> Sets a persistent variable.

Yes, it will be available across different requests.

Comment: Thanks!  Will it be stored in the database and available to a cron job days later?

Comment: Yep, it goes straight in the `variable` table

Answer (score 1):

It will be saved in the variables table and will stay there until it's either deleted or overwritten.

Comment: That's what I thought, but can you see the problem with the following code.   I will update the question now.

Comment: In addition, I'd mention that if your variable is declared in a hook_install(), then it will be cleared out when the module is uninstalled. So, this is one of many ways a variable can be deleted.